# How to convert UIImage from microsoft sql image

Tags: sql, swift

```
let image = UIImage(data: myData as! Data)
```

It comes with an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

How can I solve this?

My SQL data type is `image` and saves as HexString.

Comment: `let image = UIImage(data: myData)`

Comment: note that it should be `UIImage(data:)` with lowercase d not `UIImage(Data:)`